# ntohl used on sin_port and get negative nubmers

Tags: c, port, printf

I try to print client port in my server application which is in C.
But I get negative numbers of the Client port, what is strange behaviour:-/
Any one have an idea where could be a problem?
Part of my code which cause the problem:

```
struct sockaddr_in client_address;
int chosenPort = (int) ntohl(client_address.sin_port);
pritf("Client port is %d, chosenPort");
```

I get port like -2121400320.

Comment: You should not use `int` and `%d` (but `unsigned int` and `%u`), esp. since if `sin_port` is >32767 and one's implementation's `int` has only 16 bits, you will again can see negative numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ntohs()` instead - `sin_port` is a 16-bit value.

Comment: Also, note that ntohs() returns "unsigned short" or uint16_t.  I was confused by the "s" in the name and used short and ran into issues when converting the numbers to string values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use ntohs function instead of ntohl.
ntohs() returns 16 bit port number and ntohl will return 32 bit IP address

Now, you can get client details using getpeername()

Syntax:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
struct sockaddr_in client_address;
int getpeername(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *client, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

You can find more details using man command..